# Parent-Child Class Proper Design

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am working on a small personal project with the intention of getting more
comfortable using OOP principles and some TDD. I am wondering about an implementation
I have come up with for a generic class that will call an api and that will act
as a parent class for a variety of child classes. Below is a stripped down
example of what I am working with. I am wondering if this is properly designed?
My main concern is with the `SomeClass` and whether it is poor design to have `__init__`
call the `get` method that is in the parent `GenericAPI`? If it is poor design
I would love any advice to make it more proper. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated!

```
import requests

class GenericApi:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.response = None

def get(self):
    response = requests.get(self.url, headers=some_header)
    if response.ok:
        self.response = response
        return response
    else:
        return None


class SomeClass(GenericApi):
    def __init__(self, date):
        super().__init__(f'someurl.com/?date={date}')
        super().get()

    def formatted(self):
        data = self.response.json()
        # do some processing and return
```